# createTempFile() on Android 10 permission denied

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When attempting to create a temp file on Android 10 I am getting a permission denied error. Could someone please write a tutorial on how to create one in the external storage? Most are outdated and not for current versions of Android

Here is the logcat

```
 2020-02-22 13:46:43.766 9544-9544/com.myapp.test E/MainActivity: Image file creation failed
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2018)
    at com.myapp.test.MainActivity.create_image(MainActivity.java:915)
    at com.myapp.test.MainActivity.access$200(MainActivity.java:85)
    at com.myapp.test.MainActivity$6.onShowFileChooser(MainActivity.java:513)
    at vo.runFileChooser(PG:10)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:197)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7762)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047)
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

And code in the MainActivity.Java

```
private File create_image() throws IOException {
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    String file_name    = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_mm_ss").format(new Date());
    String new_name     = "file_"+file_name+"_";
    File sd_directory   = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    return File.createTempFile(new_name, ".jpg", sd_directory); // fails due to permission denied
}
```

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 6):

I was using official documentation to implement taking a photo from camera:

https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

yet it doesn't work and throws an exception on createTempFile method. Strangely google hasn't updated the code.

Here's a solution I've found:

Add:

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

to AndroidManifest.xml. No need to change anything in code. Works for now, but may not in upcoming Android versions.

Comment: This makes app unresponsive with no logs in Logcat.

Comment: android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" is an attribute of the application element. The Official documentation says that will be ignored from 11 version :(

Comment: So what we do in case of Android 11?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
File sd_directory   = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

to

```
File sd_directory   =  getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a file provider

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider

And request the read/write storage permissions at runtime.
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: I have a file provider already `<?xml version ="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?>

<paths>
 <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
` and the manifest reflects `<?xml version ="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?>

<paths>
 <external-path android:name="external_files" android:path="."/>
</paths>
` However thanks for referring me to nonsensical information at the android dev site. I guess because the android dev site exists there is no reason for people to ask questions here now

Answer (score 0):

In android 10 permission isn't directly accepted. So, you have ask from user to accept permission. There's a library which you can use for asking permission. Let me add that [link](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter)

It is known as Dexter Library

You have to add a line to `gradle.build`

```
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.2'
```

Following source code used for single permission at a time.

```
Dexter.withContext(this)
.withPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
.withListener(new PermissionListener() {
    @Override public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {/* ... */}
    @Override public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {/* ... */}
    @Override public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {/* ... */}
}).check();
```

There's way to asking for multiple permission in `Dexter` library. You can get that on that [link](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` In android 10+, you can't write on public folder directly. One way is to use `getExternalFilesDir` to capture image and then use [MediaStore](https://androidexplained.github.io/android/android11/scoped-storage/2020/09/29/file-saving-android-11.html) APIs to copy file into public directory.